# Unable to resolve dependency issue on ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm fairly new to this `ROR` application, so please understand if my wordings for describing my problem is not as accurate.

I'm now trying to replicate what the github below is doing.

https://github.com/harrystech/prelaunchr

I'm figuring out with the Developer Setup part, but when I execute

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

the result in my command is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):    20: from
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'   19:
>   from
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:309:in`
>   activate_bin_path'   18: from
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:309:in
>   `synchronize'     17: from
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:311:in`
>   block in activate_bin_path'  16: from
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:243:in
>   `finish_resolve'  15: from
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:397:in`
>   resolve_current'     14: from
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:385:in
>   `resolve'     13: from
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:188:in`
>   resolve'     12: from
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:42:in
>   `resolve'     11: from
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:64:in`
>   resolve'     10: from
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:106:in
>   `start_resolution'     9: from
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:165:in`
>   initial_state'    8: from
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:51:in
>   `sort_dependencies'    7: from
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:69:in`
>   with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'   6: from
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:52:in
>   `block in sort_dependencies'   5: from
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:277:in`
>   sort_dependencies'    4: from
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:277:in
>   `with_index'   3: from
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:277:in`
>   sort_by'      2: from
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:277:in
>   `each'     1: from
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:283:in`
>   block in sort_dependencies'
>   /home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:231:in
>   `search_for': Unable to resolve dependency: user requested
>   'did_you_mean (= 1.2.0)' (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError)

By the way I'm using ubuntu..

Okay, I had some progress on the error. I found out that there might be a version error with my bundler, and that I have to use **bundler -v 1.15.0.pre.3** . So i did as following, but this time , when i do

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

the output is

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:6:in `connection'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:15:in `create'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:107:in `block in create_current'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:278:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:277:in `each'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:277:in `each_current_configuration'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:106:in `create_current'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `block in execute'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `each'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `execute'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `invoke'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:360:in `exec'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/exe/bundle:35:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/exe/bundle:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "database"=>"prelaunchr_development", "host"=>"localhost"}
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:6:in `connection'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:15:in `create'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:107:in `block in create_current'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:278:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:277:in `each'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:277:in `each_current_configuration'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:106:in `create_current'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `block in execute'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `each'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `execute'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `invoke'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:360:in `exec'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/exe/bundle:35:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0.pre.3/exe/bundle:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/leesungyong/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "database"=>"prelaunchr_test", "host"=>"localhost"}
```

I'm getting really tired of this ROR building..  can someone please help me with the build??

Comment: your `bundle install` works fine without any errors ?

Comment: actually when i did bundle install it had version issues, so I changed the version with 1.3.0.

Comment: What gem's version did you change? What version did you use before? How did you change the version?

Comment: To be exact, when i did "bundle"  ------>   "rails (~> 4.2) was resolved to 4.2.11, which depends on bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)".

 So, I uninstalled my current bundler and installed bundler -v 1.3.0 by "gem install bundler -v 1.3.0" command. My gem version is 2.7.6. Technically I did not change my gem version, but my bundler version.